# troubleshooting MATLAB Iteration code

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, iteration

I have an iteration code which I am using to find latitude/longitude of a set of heights (h_intercept). This is a 1x79 matrix.

It works perfectly until the 22nd value. I've found that this is when h_test>h_intercept. I tried to put a condition in to reset it but it doesn't work.

When h_test>h_intercept, all of the range values become zero

For example

```
for j=20:40
rng_sat= sat_look_tcs_pass1(3,j); 
  u_sat=[sat_look_tcs_pass1(1,j)/sat_look_tcs_pass1(3,j);sat_look_tcs_pass1(2,j)/sat_look_tcs_pass1(3,j);sat_look_tcs_pass1(3,j)/sat_look_tcs_pass1(3,j)];
h_intercept=sat_look_pass1_llh(3,j)/2e3;
  h_test=zeros(1,3);
rng_test_min=0;
rng_test_max=rng_sat/2e3;
err=0.01;
while abs(h_intercept-h_test)>err   
    rng_test=(rng_test_min+rng_test_max)/2;
    tcs_test=u_sat*rng_test;
    llh_test=tcs2llhT(tcs_test,station_llh);
    h_test=llh_test(3,:);
     if h_test>=h_intercept
         rng_test_max=rng_test; 
    else
        rng_test_min=rng_test;
    end
end copter_llh(:,j)=(llh_test); h_interceptloop(:,j)=(h_intercept); end % code end
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in the first loop. In the first line you choose values 60 to 79:

```
h_intercept=sat_look_pass1_llh(3,60:79)/2e3;
```

However, you only use the length of that vector and not its values in the following code.
You iterate over the length of `h_intercept`, i.e. from 1 to 19:

```
for j=1:length(h_intercept)
```

which means that `h_intercept=sat_look_pass1_llh(3,j)/2e3;` will get the wrong value, as j ranges from 1 to 19 and not from 60 to 79.

If you change your for loop to `for j=60:79`, it should work ( and you can also delete the first line `h_intercept=sat_look_pass1_llh(3,60:79)/2e3;` )

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply! Wow, so silly of me. However, it still doesn't work for h_test>H_intercept